# Replace with captured group in Julia

Tags: regex, julia

I’m trying to use the `replace` function, the doc specifies

> replace(string::AbstractString, pat, r[, n::Integer=0])
>
> Search for the given pattern pat, and replace each occurrence with r. If n is provided, replace at most n occurrences.
>   As with search, the second argument may be a single character, a vector or a set of characters, a string, or a regular
>   expression. If r is a function, each occurrence is replaced with r(s) where s is the matched substring. If pat is a
>   regular expression and r is a SubstitutionString, then capture group references in r are replaced with the
>   corresponding matched text.

I don’t understand the last sentence and couldn’t find `SubstitutionString` (there is `SubString` though, but I also couldn't directly find doc for that). I’d like to do a replace where `r` uses the captured group(s) indicated in `pat`. Something that corresponds to the following simple example in Python:

```
regex.sub(r'#(.+?)#', r"captured:\1", "hello #target# bye #target2#")
```

which returns `'hello captured:target bye captured:target2'`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A `SubstitutionString` can be created via `s""`. Similarly to how you'd create regexes with `r""`. These then can be used as a pair `from => to` to tell Julia how to replace matched strings.

Julia (1.8+)

```
julia> replace("hello #target# bye #target2#",  r"#(.+?)#" => s"captured:\1")
"hello captured:target bye captured:target2"
```

Older version:

```
julia> replace("hello #target# bye #target2#",  r"#(.+?)#", s"captured:\1")
"hello captured:target bye captured:target2"
```

If you search for `substitution string` in https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/strings/ you'll find another example there.

Comment: The docs definitely need improvements here. At least, `SubstitutionString` should have a docstring, the `replace` docs should link to it, and an example should be given. I've filed an issue: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/26497.

Comment: this no longer works I get `MethodError: no method matching replace(::String, ::Regex, ::SubstitutionString{String})`

Comment: @Mark Thanks for that. I updated the answer to work on the latest Julia version.

Answer (score 7):

It has changed since last answer. Current correct version is this one

```
replace("first second", r"(\w+) (?<agroup>\w+)" => s"\g<agroup> \1")
replace("a", r"." => s"\g<0>1")
```

See https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/strings/ for more details.