# Replace matching paris of the same string with different strings in Julia

Tags: string, julia

I've got long string. In this string I have many instances of the syntax `"$$ inline equation here $$"`. I want to replace that with `"\( inline equation here \)"`. I can't just use a naive `replace`, since the operation needs to switch between `\(` and `\)` for each matching pair of `$$` `$$`. One idea I had was to input a function to `replace` that checks a global boolean variable, and based on whether the global boolean is true or false it will replace `$$` with either `\(` or `\)`, and then finishes by switching the value of the global boolean. However, this feels like a pretty hacky solution. Does anyone have better ideas? Is there a regex that solves this perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
text = "The world is full of cool equations, such as: \$\$E = mc^2\$\$, \$\$F = ma\$\$, and \$\$a^2 + b^2 = c^2\$\$."

# find all the instances of $$something$$ and replace them with \(something)]
for equation in findall(r"\$\$(.*?)\$\$", text)
    text = text[1:equation[1]-1] * "\\(" * text[equation[3:end-2]] * "\\)" * text[equation[end]+1:end]
end
#"The world is full of cool equations, such as: \\(E = mc^2\\), \\(F = ma\\), and \\(a^2 + b^2 = c^2\\)."
```

Update: Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69522216/4145280), I learned about [`SubstitutionString`s](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/#Base.SubstitutionString). In one line:

`replace(text, r"\$\$(.*?)\$\$" => s"\\(\1\\)")`

Comment: Marvelous! My regex game is embarrassingly weak. Thanks!